# How to (tilt) rotate a 500 by 1000 matrix? - Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, rotation

I am trying to tilt a 500 by 1000 matrix by 5 degrees then colormap the new matrix.

I start by calling the data from a .txt file into the Matrix A:

```
rows = 1000;
cols = 500;
theta = pi/36;   %5 Degrees
fid = fopen('TEST.txt', 'r');
A = fscanf(fid, '%f', [cols rows])';    %transpose so rows of matrix correspond to rows in text

fclose(fid)
```

After that I would like to tilt this data by 5 degrees. I was hoping to use the `makehgtform` function in Matlab but with no success yet. This is what i attempted:

```
R = makehgtform('zrotate', theta);
R = R(1:3,1:3);
Try(1:500,1:1000) = 1;
center = repmat(Try,1,1);
so = R*(s-center) + center;
```

This section above is where I keep getting errors, and I haven't been able to find the correct solution. Ideally after this point I would then colormap the new matrix as follows:

```
%figure('Renderer', 'painters', 'Position', [10 10 500 1000])
imagesc(so)
colorbar;
caxis([0 100])
shading interp
```

So far I have not succeeded and I am at my wits end on how to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`imrotate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imrotate.html) exactly for that purpose:

```
Ans=imrotate(your_matrix,5);
```

If you still prefer the other way:

```
phi =deg2rad(5);
Rot_matrix = [cos(phi) sin(phi) 0; -sin(phi) cos(phi) 0; 0 0 1];
tform_R =maketform('affine', Rot_matrix );
resamp = makeresampler({'linear','linear'},'fill'); % (interpolant, pad-method)
Ans=imtransform(your_matrix,tform_R ,resamp);
imagesc(Ans)
```